# react-native Redux updating state when returning

Tags: react-native

**MY OBJECT**

```
const initialState = {
1: {
    id: 1,
   price: 280
},
2: {
    id: 2,
    price: 200
}
```

}

**ACTION**

I want to take away $100 for the item user has clicked on. The console log works fine when I click on first Item it gives me 180. But how can I do that In my return function. I tried many times but nothing updated.

```
switch (action.type) {
  case 'BUY_ITEM':
    const getId = state[action.index]['price']
    console.log(getId - 100)
    //this console.log works fine
        return {

        }
   }
   return state
}


 <FlatList
 style={{ flex: 1 }}
 data={Object.values(this.props.data)}
 keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()
 }
   renderItem={({ item }) => {
     return (
        <Card style={styles.itemcontainer}>
             <Text style={[styles.text, { fontSize: 20,}]}>${item.price}</Text>
           <Button style={styles.buyItem} bordered onPress={() => this.props.boughtItem(item.id)}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 17, paddingHorizontal: 25, color: '#333945', textAlign: 'center' }}>
         <FontAwesome name="cart-plus" style={styles.buyIcon} />
                                {'  '}Add to cart
                                </Text>
                        </Button>
                    </Card >
                )
            }}>
        </FlatList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't directly change `state`. Check below code,

```
switch (action.type) {
  case "BUY_ITEM":
    return {
      ...state,
      [action.index]: {
        ...state[action.index],
        price: state[action.index]["price"] - 100,
      },
    };
}
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Hello thanks for replying. It works but can I change certain price. I tried your answer it changed my first objects price to 180. Which works fine but when I clicked on my second object it set the price of first object back to 280.